# Langchain: Unable to access the table names, which are in synonyms, views by using langchain SQLDatabasechain and oracle database

Tags: python-3.x, oracle-sqldeveloper, openai-api, langchain

I'm new to this langchain. Here, what I'm trying to build is a text-to-sql application. But I am unable to access the table names, which are in synonyms, views by using langchain SQLDatabasechain. Could anyone help me out with this?
Here is the code. Please have a look and tell me where I made the mistake.

```
import os
import sys
import cx_Oracle
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import constants       #Importing OpenAPIKey from constants file
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY


# Declaring Database Details
IP="IP Address"
PORT="POSRT"
servicename="ORACLE_SERVICENAME"
username="USERNAME"
password="PASSWORD"


# Developing the oracle Connection
oracle_connection_string_fmt = (f'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@' +  cx_Oracle.makedsn(f'{IP}', f'{PORT}', service_name=f'{servicename}'))
url = oracle_connection_string_fmt.format(username=username, password=password, hostname=IP, port=PORT, service_name=servicename,)

engine=create_engine(url, echo=True)
db = SQLDatabase(engine)
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.01, verbose=True)

db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True)

while True:
    query = input("Query Please: ")  # query = "Is employee code 7365 exist or not?"
    if query in ('q', 'quit', 'exit'):
        break
        sys.exit()
    value = db_chain.run(query)
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change just the above syntax to:

```
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase

oracle_connection_string_fmt = SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"oracle+cx_oracle://{userName}:password}@{host}/{service_name}",sample_rows_in_table_info=3)
```